# What's the difference between apostasy and heresy?

Tags: terminology, heresy, comparative-religion, apostasy

[Apostasy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostasy)

> Apostasy (/əˈpɒstəsi/; Greek: ἀποστασία apostasía, 'a defection or revolt') is the formal disaffiliation from, abandonment of, or renunciation of a religion by a person. It can also be defined within the broader context of embracing an opinion that is contrary to one's previous religious beliefs. One who undertakes apostasy is known as an apostate. Undertaking apostasy is called apostatizing (or apostasizing – also spelled apostacizing). The term apostasy is used by sociologists to mean the renunciation and criticism of, or opposition to, a person's former religion, in a technical sense, with no pejorative connotation. ~ Wikipedia

[Heresy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heresy)

> Heresy is any belief or theory that is strongly at variance with established beliefs or customs, in particular the accepted beliefs of a church or religious organization. The term is usually used in reference to violations of important religious teachings, but is also used of views strongly opposed to any generally accepted ideas. A heretic is a proponent of heresy. ~Wikipedia

Is it possible to be a heretic and not an apostate and vice versa? What about in other religions like Islam?

Comment: this *might* go better on philosophy SE

Comment: Why do you say that? "Philosophy is the handmaid of religion" ~ Saint Thomas Aquinas.

Comment: Heresy - a holding to certain views contrary to authoritative works or people in a religion, while still claiming the religion
Apostasy - outright rejection of the religion

Comment: So a Christian heretic is still a Christian while a Christian apostate isn't a Christian. Gracias.

Comment: this isn't really about Christianity but meaning/interpretation/application of the word. philosophy may be considered the handmaid of religion but there is a reason there are separate SEs, same for biblical hermeneutics, even other more similar topics should be asked in the right place. I did say *might* as there may be some work that discusses this point from a denomination perspective, but IMO it doesn't seem like a match for the site, very broad and opinion based

Comment: Apologies if the question failed to meet your standards. I hope the mods give due consideration to your critique. Have a nice day. 

Comment: @depperm I disagree. Having studied both, theology defines apostasy and heresy. Philosophy does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Apostasy* and *Heresy* are **always** defined relative to the perspective of a religion or a religion's sect/denomination**.  Since we are dealing with many denominations and many religions, this answer is about the common meaning of those 2 *terminologies* that most denominations / religions use.

The *Wikipedia* articles you cited are quite clear in the definitions:

- **Heresy**: belief that is *strongly at variance* with established beliefs
- **Apostasy**: *renunciation or abandonment* of a religion

#### Can one be a heretic but not an apostate, or vice versa?

Of course one can.  Let's say I am a Unitarian who has never been a Catholic.  From the Catholic Church point of view,  **I am NOT an *apostate* since I have never been a Catholic, but I AM a *heretic*** since by being a Unitarian I'm rejecting the belief in one of the most central dogmas of Catholicism: the Trinity.

If later I take a *further* step in denying Christianity altogether then the Catholic Church will call me an *apostate* because I used to be a Christian, albeit a "*heretical*" one.  Similarly, if I am a Presbyterian and I decide to become a Buddhist, I would be an *apostate* from the Presbyterian Church's point of view because I abandon Christianity.  Since I am no longer a Christian, I can no longer be called a *heretic* from any Christian denomination's point of view.  **Thus I can be an *apostate* but not a *heretic*.**

But let's say I'm a Protestant who converts to Catholicism.  I *may* or *may not* be called a *heretic* depending on how stringent my previous church is.  This is because of ecumenism effort in the late 20th century where as long as someone belongs to a mainstream Christian group he/she can usually switch between mainstream groups without incurring the label *heretic*.  But several non-denominational churches with a fundamentalist tendency can still call me a *heretic* if I become a Catholic.

#### Can one be an apostate while STILL professing to be a Christian?

YES, but this would be apostasy in a DIFFERENT sense: *behavioral* instead of *intellectual*.  The extensive and detailed *Wikipedia* article [Apostasy in Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostasy_in_Christianity) covers the behavioral aspect in its sections on Biblical teaching, Patristic teaching, Reformers' teaching, as well as provide links to specific denomination's view.  Some examples of "*behavioral*" apostasy:

1. Bible's imagery of Israel's breaking covenant relationship with God through disobedience to the law (Jer 2:19-29) or worshipping *other* gods in addition to YHWH (Judges 2:19, Jer 2:1-3, Eze 16)
2. Early church fathers' labelling of these behaviors as "*apostasy*" although the Christians were not renouncing their beliefs (see [this article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostasy_in_Christianity#Views_of_the_early_church_fathers) for details):

   - Persistent and willful immorality, rivalry & envy that split the community, refusing to be corrected
   - Denying Christ out of fear (but not in their heart) during persecutions
   - Being extremely deceived by false teachers until the faith is no longer recognizably Christian; thus it is MORE than *heresy* (in Patristic understanding, *heresy* is "walking a different path", i.e. following non-orthodox but still recognizably Christian such as following Arian teaching)

#### What about in other religions like Islam?

In my limited understanding, if a Moslem converts to become a Christian, he/she would be an *apostate* from all Moslem groups' point of view.  But if a Sunni Moslem becomes a Shia Moslem, that *may* or *may not* qualify him/her of being a *heretical* Moslem (see Quora answer [Do Sunnis and Shiites see each other as heresy?](https://qr.ae/prIFen))  See also the article [Heresy in Islam](https://religion.fandom.com/wiki/Heresy_in_Islam) describing how belonging to one of the smaller Islam sects (such as the Alawis, or the Sufis) may count as *heresy* from the point of view of a larger group such as the Wahhabis.

#### CONCLUSION

- The occasions where one is called an *apostate* are relative to the religion you *used to belong*.
- The occasions where one is called a *heretic* are relative to *another group* within the same religion that you *currently belong*.

Comment: You may be a heretic, but at least you're not a heresiarch!

Comment: Muchas gracias. So if I leave Christianity, I'm an apostate, but if I, for instance, refuse to endorse the Holy Trinity, I'm a heretic. 

Comment: @AgentSmith Assuming you currently belongs to one of the mainstream Christian groups, yes .  But I doubt that your ex-Christian friend will call you that to your face; they would try to address your concerns and win you back.  But as PeterTurner said, at least you're not the founder of a heresy :-).

Comment: I accepted the answer. It's a thoughtful and fact-based answer. Kudos to you. Just wondering, is it true that Christians had more problems with heresy than apostasy while the converse is true for Islam?

Comment: @AgentSmith no, if you deny the trinity you are only a heretic relative to the  Catholics, not to God.

Comment: I would have to agree. According to Wikipedia, Issac Newton didn't believe in the Trinity, but he is also described as a devout Christian.

Comment: @AgentSmith You asked "Is it true that Christians had more problems with heresy than apostasy while the converse is true for Islam?"  It appears so since, according to a 2015 study, [more Muslims converted to Christianity than vice versa](https://qr.ae/prI5j0).  Also Christianity has been dealing with heresies since the very first century starting with Gnosticism and to 20th century with New Age, Oneness Pentecostal, etc.  Maybe the freedom in Christian countries since 1648 contributed to new heresies being produced.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, 